# Can I retrieve data from database via .dll in Reporting service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

Can I use .dll File to retrieve data from Database in Reporting Service. For example Retrieve Data in Dataset using .dll like this

> "= Code.getData() "

If can do .Then how to send parameter to code

Thank you

(If you have url for detail this problem give it to me Thank you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed the .dll file and use the custom assemblies in SSRS. Please refer to the Microsoft KB:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769